# Can someone explain the "returning to the past" motif in Logan?

Tags: analysis, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In Logan, there is a very prominent motif of returning to the past. Laura and Gabriel both had old X-Men comics, and of course the lat/lon location of the fictional Eden in the comics was used as a gathering point. The vehicles they drove regressed from the futuristic Cadillac, to a ~2000 used truck, to a beat-up old wagon from ~80s. And lastly, there's the kids cutting old Logan's beard hair to match his classic Wolverine look.

I didn't understand the purpose of this motif in the story. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because it symbolizes Logan's return to his heroic roots. The movie starts with him avoiding fights, hiding and scraping for money,  being a shit to Xavier. By the end he does everything he can to save the kids, like he did in the past. The movie represents nostalgia for better times, while also representing the old passing the torch to the new generation.

It was also a ham fisted analogy for avoiding some of the new trends in the modern world, like the movie showed with the auto-trucks and corporate farms and gmo vs the family with horses and small family farm and natural food. The movie shows the future sucks compared to traditional beliefs.